# How to rapidly play a sound when button is clicked(android)

Tags: java, android, audio, android-studio

I'm trying to play a sound each time, a button is clicked. The sound is played but I need to play it every single time(like the sound played when you type something), the problem is, mine isn't playing always. I think this is because the button is clicked with very little delay.

```
    new MediaPlayer sound = new MediaPlayer().create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (x >= pS.getX() && x < (pS.getX() + squareS.getWidth()) &&
                y >= pS.getY() && y < (pS.getY() + squareS.getHeight())) {
            pS.setRes(pSquareOffRes);
            pS.setX(pS.getX() - squareS.getWidth());
            pS.setY(pS.getY() - squareS.getHeight());
            pS.setTouched(true);
            pS.lock(true);
            touchLimitA = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timer = 3;
            sound.start();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am glad of any advice you can give :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need low latency playback you should use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

Comment: @Traviss you can preload some sound too. By the way, can you upvote my answer too?